# Run different webapp images on single Tomcat instance through docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Currently I have 2 web applications (WAR) app1 and app2 running on Tomcat 7:

app1 on http://localhost:8080/app1

app2 on http://localhost:8080/app2

I have created two different images in docker for webapp app1 and app2.

Now I want to run both the images in docker so that I can access the application with the same host and ports: i.e.: localhost:8080/app1 and localhost:8080/app2

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) for this purpose. docker-compose can build multiple containers for you on the same 'host'. You may include other services in docker-compose as you need, let's say a database or redis service. Then run the docker-compose up command.

```
$ docker-compose -f 'myapps-docker-compose.yml' up -d
```

where `-f` is 'from file' and `-d` is detached.
Your Sample docker-compose file called `myapps-docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2.1'
#
services:
    redis:
        image: 'redis:5.0.5'
        # command: redis-server --requirepass redispass

    app1:
        image: app1
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile_app1
    app2:
        image: app2
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile_app2
```